# Loop for document.getElementById in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have two tabs in html. 
In the 1st tab i have some options, such as textarea, option list, checkbox... 
I want my app to show/transfer whatever i choose (in the 1st tab) to the 2nd tab as text, when i click an "ok" button.

In the js script i put the following function:

```
function myFunction() {
  var r="";
  var x="";
  var y="";
  var z="";

  var i;
  for (i=0; i++){
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
    var r = x + " " + y +" " + z ;
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = r;

}
```

where the result is shown in the 2nd tab as follows:

```
<p id="result"></p>
```

My problem is that it doesn't show every time what I choose in the 1st tab, but every time I click the "ok" button, the 2nd tab shows my last options. In other words I want the 2nd tab to show all of my options every time I click 'ok'. It is obvious that i make a mistake in the loop for. But what is it?

Please help me...

Comment: 1. for loop not complete - missing the while/until clause; 2. r being calculated over and over if there was an until clause; 3 why loop? You are not using the i anywhere - you can remove `var r="";
  var x="";
  var y="";
  var z="";

  var i;
  for (i=0; i++){` and the `}` after the SECOND `var r`

Comment: If you declare once a variable, then you didn't need to declare it again. e.g in your code `var r=""` declare twice.

Comment: This will work better: `function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= document.getElementById("myTextarea").value +" "+
    document.getElementById("mySelect").value +" "+
    document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
}`

Comment: Thank you, but this code shows every time only my new options and replaces my previous options with the new. I want it to show all the options every time.

Comment: In other words, i want to take the result every time i click ok in the 1st tab, without remove the previous result. Something like this:                                         result    (1st time)                                                                        result    (2nd)                                                                             result    (3rd)                                                                             ........  (...)

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to add a string per click, you should not need a loop. Instead add content to the existing content using either `innerHTML += ...`, or better: use DOM methods to add a text node to the DOM.

Here is how that could look:

```js
function addToResult() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
    var r = x + " - " + y + " - " + z;
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r));
    result.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
var addButton = document.getElementById("add");
addButton.addEventListener("click", addToResult);
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea><br>
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>choice 1</option>
    <option>choice 2</option>
</select>
<select id="mySelect2">
    <option>choice A</option>
    <option>choice B</option>
</select><br>

<button id="add">Add</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It works excellent! And something else... if i want to choose some of these registers which are shown in the 2nd tab (for example by ticking them using checkbox), so as to delete them, is it possible? What i need ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but then you should really try first, creating the checkboxes with `document.createElement('input');`, then setting the type attribute to `checkbox`, with `setAttribute`, then binding a click handler to it, with `addEventListener("click", ...)`, and finally deleting that element again with `elem.removeChild(...)`. Look up those methods and try first. If you really get stuck, ask a new question with the particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method to add more content.

```js
function $(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector)
}

function addToResult() {
    var x = $("#myTextarea").value;
    var y = $("#mySelect").value;
    var z = $("#mySelect2").value;
    var r = x + " - " + y + " - " + z;
    
    $("#result").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', r)
}
var addButton = document.getElementById("add");
addButton.addEventListener("click", addToResult);
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea><br>
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>choice 1</option>
    <option>choice 2</option>
</select>
<select id="mySelect2">
    <option>choice A</option>
    <option>choice B</option>
</select><br>

<button id="add">Add</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```